# index.ctp not recognized in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have created index.ctp under views/controller_name/ folder, but the **Missing view** error is still appearing? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This one depends on the URL you try to reach. If you open yourwebsite.com/yourcontroller, you are supposed to view the index.ctp view from your views/yourcontroller directory. However, you might use a routed configuration and therefore redirect your URL to another path (controller+view combination at that matter).